# Query string oData filter use with greater than operator

Tags: c#, filter, odata

I have a get API and it is using oData filter mechanism to filtering data. My filtering is working fine. But there is nested object and it has a key, value. What I want is to filtering out with specific key and value. It also works fine. But there is key called "InsuredValue". So I need to filter insurance value is greater than 1000. But it occurred "*The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.String' and 'System.String'*" error. Possible issue is both key and value's data type is string. String data cannot be used greater than operator. Below I added my entities and query string that I tried.

```
public class Employee
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
        public List<EmpAttributes> Attributes { get; set; }
}


public class EmpAttributes
{
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

*/api/services/app/Employee/GetEmployees?Filter=Attributes/any(x: x/type eq 'InsuredValue' and x/value gt '1000')*

Any expert who can show me a direction to cast string data and apply greater than operator with above filter mechanism?

Comment: please share the definition of your InsuredValue, also based on the definition you are creating, your URI design is not REST, which is one thing that OData promotes, you should do a GET request to api/services/app/Employee?Filter =..... the GetEmployees is redundant, the HTTP verb already gives that semantic to the request

Comment: Thanks zinov for replying. InsuredValue is decimal value and it store in a string type column. The reason is, this EmpAttribute table is used to store a lot of information which is employee specific. So we cannot make a table and define column names for that. If that happens we have to include new columns day by day. We are using the prefix "Get" as naming convention for get requests. What my issue is to filter oData query with "gt" (or lt). It seems kind of casting can do it. But one of stackoverflow questions mentioned casting cannot be apply to oData. If so what would be the way to do this?

Comment: I know, what I am saying is that you should not use that type of conventions with OData, but going with your question, you have a workaround, on your controller action method you can receive an ODataQueryOptions<Dto> from there you can access your filter property and get the value options.Filter.RawValue. You will need to parse your query and you can execute your query, but you are not deferring the execution to OData extensions for IQueryable on this way. Take a look here of what you can do as well https://github.com/hassanhabib/ODataNextPOC/blob/master/ConsoleApp18/Program.cs